# How many milliseconds do "slow", "normal", and "fast" represent in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, effects, jquery-effects

jQuery allows use of the string values "slow", "normal", and "fast" in animations (e.g.: `$('#example').fadeOut('slow');`).  How many milliseconds do each of these values represent?

Comment: I dont think `normal` is a special arguement. But since you supplied, other than 'slow' / 'flow' , it considered 400.

Comment: @Jashwant - no need to make invalid assumptions.  I did research the docs, and unless they've been updated since I asked this question, the millisecond values were not mentioned.

Comment: I didnt get you. Where am I making invalid assumption ? :O

Comment: You said, "it deserves -1 for no research."  But I did research.

Comment: I removed that :) I just said what I thought.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

600, 400 and 200, respectively "slow", "normal", "fast". [All in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Thanks, didn't see it in there. Appreciate the reference!

Comment: Just to add, there's nothing in special in `normal` like `slow` or `fast`. From the same link, `If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of 400 milliseconds is used`

Answer (score 11):

600ms, 400ms and 200ms respectively.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: Thanks for adding the link.  Unfortunately, it only explains the speeds of fast and slow, not normal.

Comment: Actually it is 600, 400, 200 respectively =)

Comment: @Matt Huggins, I think "normal" is default value, which is 400. You can take a look at the source yourself (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js) line 5885.

Comment: if I recall, the docs only specify slow and fast, and any other value returns 400. So, .fadeOut('monkeyFeces') will fade out at 400 ms. (Try it)

Answer (score 6):

I would be original and answer 600, 400, 200 respectively. Since higher number of milliseconds means slower speed =) [All in the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js)